# Can you remove identifying information when saving an image with Photoshop?

Tags: image, file, adobe, photoshop

I'm wondering if it's possible to remove or change identifying information when saving an image with Photoshop?

I feel that when I registered my Photoshop I used my first and last name. Is it possible to remove my last name, or replace it with an initial instead?

Answer (score 1):

Go to your Adobe account and make changes to your profile details. Save it and re-login to your Photoshop using Adobe Creative Cloud interface.

Comment: I don't have Adobe Creative Cloud Interface. I'm using a pretty old version of Photoshop, from 2015. Is there a way to do this on my version?